# How to run a video in autoplay, auto reply and muted

Tags: iframe, video, youtube, mute

I want to add the code below to a blog and add parameters auto play, auto replay, and play in mute. Can you please help how to change the code that will work fine? Since this video is hosted on youtube but I am prompting this through a network can you please help me to add these paramaters. I tried adding `&=autoplay` but it doesn't work:

```
<iframe src="http://tyroodirect.com/stats/ps/Video/bacardi/dt/video4.html?src=http://affiliates.tyroodr.com/ez/ckqqeapkxasxzi/" width="300" height="256" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: First show what you have done. Please post your code first.

Comment: I have the below code with me and wanted to add this in a blog nothing much i hvr done.................<iframe src="http://tyroodirect.com/stats/ps/Video/bacardi/dt/video4.html?src=http://affiliates.tyroodr.com/ez/dxwwbkcxskmshr/" width="300" height="256" frameborder="0"></iframe>